# check the authority of performing an action through openshift rest api

Tags: rest, cmd, authorization, openshift

In [openshift doc](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/architecture/additional_concepts/authorization.html#authorization-determining-what-you-can-do-as-an-authenticated-user), we can check the ability of performing an action with a single command:

```
oc policy can-i <verb> <resource>
```

but how could i achieve this (To determine if you can perform specific verbs on specific resources) through its rest api

Answer (score 0):

Use the service account name for what the applications will run as:

```
$ oc policy can-i --list --user system:serviceaccount:myproject:default
Verbs     Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   API Groups   Resources

$ oc create serviceaccount jupyterhub
$ oc policy add-role-to-user edit -z jupyterhub

$ oc policy can-i --list --user system:serviceaccount:myproject:jupyterhub
Verbs                                                                      Non-Resource URLs   Resource Names   API Groups                Resources
[create delete deletecollection get impersonate list patch update watch]   []                  []               []                        [serviceaccounts]
[create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]               []                  []               []                        [buildconfigs]
[create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]               []                  []               []                        [buildconfigs/webhooks]
....
```

Applications will run as `default` normally. Here I created a new service account called `jupyterhub` and gave it `edit` role. I then queried what it could do. Replace `myproject` with name of your project and replace `jupyterhub` with name of your service account or `default` if you are changing what role it has.

This presumes you are wanting to use the REST API from an application.

For an application it is actually pretty easy, you either give it `view`, `edit` or `admin` role.

- admin: A project manager. The user will have rights to view any resource in the project and modify any resource in the project except for quota. A user with this role for a project will be able to delete the project.
- edit: A user that can modify most objects in a project, but does not have the power to view or modify roles or bindings. A user with this role can create and delete applications in the project.
- view: A user who cannot make any modifications, but can see most objects in a project.

Even if a normal user account and doing it from outside of the cluster, still not going to be much different in way you interpret it, just going to use the users account name instead. Although if doing it for yourself, wouldn't need `--user` option.

Comment: this seems to be the way using cli, what i want is how to achieve this with an http request, is there any ways?

Comment: Run the command using the ``--loglevel 9`` option. It will show you what requests it makes to the REST API to do it.

Answer (score 0):

find a way, use this command:

```
oc policy can-i get pods --loglevel=8
```

then i can see the api being called by this cmd, which is:

```
POST https://openshift-cluster.example.com:8443/oapi/v1/subjectaccessreviews
```

Answer (score 0):

In OpenShift since version 4:

```bash
oc auth can-i --list --as=myuser

# as a service account
oc auth can-i --list --as=system:serviceaccount:mynamespace:myserviceaccountname
```